# How can I optmize this query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deno

Here is the full query:

```
  async getHistoryByTag(context: StandardContext) {
    const { mongo } = context.state;
    const tag = context.params.tag.replace(/-+/g, " ");
    const today = new Date();
    const prevSunday = getOneWeekAgo(today);

    console.log("today: ", today, "prev sunday: ", prevSunday);

    const all = await mongo
      .collection("search_history")
      .aggregate<SearchHistoryModel & { username: string; word: string }>([
        {
          $match: {
            created_at: { $gt: prevSunday.toISOString() },
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user_id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "user",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  username: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },

        // { search_id: 1, created_at: 1, url: 1 }
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "positive",
            localField: "search_id",
            foreignField: "search_id",
            as: "positive",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  word: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$user",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$positive",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$user", "$positive"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            word: tag,
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            user: 0,
            positive: 0,
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            created_at: -1,
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray();

    context.response.body = all.filter((value, index, self) => {
      return self.findIndex((v) => v.url === value.url) === index;
    });
  }
```

I've tried adding indexes but it still takes 5-10 seconds to respond.

Comment: Please also show the indexes on the collections and a query plan mongodb is using (run explain). Number of docs in each collection will certainly help along with the RAM of the machine.

Comment: what command do I run for `explain`? Machine has 64gb ram

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/

Comment: `> db.search_history.explain('allPlansExecution')
Explainable(grazily.search_history`

Answer (score 0):

You need only to re-order the mongo pipeline a bit.

match and sort should be first to use indexes, also do not use match of a populated property in the root pipeline but in the populate pipeline instead.

so, your pipeline should be something like that.

```js
    const all = await mongo
      .collection("search_history")
      .aggregate<SearchHistoryModel & { username: string; word: string }>([
        // match should be first
        {
          $match: {
            created_at: { $gt: prevSunday.toISOString() },
          },
        },
        // sort should be second
        {
          $sort: {
            created_at: -1,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user_id",
            foreignField: "id",
            as: "user",
            pipeline: [
              {
                $project: {
                  username: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "positive",
            localField: "search_id",
            foreignField: "search_id",
            as: "positive",
            pipeline: [
              {    
                $match: {word: tag},   // move the populated match inside the populate pipeline to use the index
              }
              {
                $project: {
                  word: 1,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$user",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$positive",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$user", "$positive"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            user: 0,
            positive: 0,
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray();
```

Note: if your collection is huge use pagination for faster quires.

Comment: This looks like the right answer to me. Be sure the `positive` collection has an index like `{ word: 1 }`

Comment: I get an error on this line: `aggregate<SearchHistoryModel & { username: string; word: string }>([`

Comment: what is the error message?